Runge-Kutta methods that use exact solution
I have an ODE system of the form, with $A(u)$ being stiff
$$
\dot u = A(u) + B(u)
$$
I know the exact solution of the ODE
$$
\dot u = A(u)
$$
Are there Runge-Kutta methods which can make use of this ?
If $A(u) = A u $ with $A=$constant, then I can write
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (S(-t)u) = S(-t)B(u), \qquad S(t) = \exp(t A)
$$
and apply any RK method. But I am interested in the case where $A(u)$ is non-linear but I still know its solution operator.

I guess this is related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180948/generalizing-variation-of-parameters

Thank you, this is the first step towards a solution. I am sure somebody has already come up with an RK method to approximate the remaining integral in the solution formula.

What you have is a nonlinear Volterra integral equation, so you could look for methods applicable to such problems, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0771050X81900450
I think the general idea of solving $u(T) = f(T) + \int_0^T g(\tau, T, u(\tau)),d\tau$ would be to discretise $[0,T]$ and solve $\tilde{u}(t_i) = f(t_i) + \sum_{k=0}^{i} c_{i,k} g(t_k, t_i, \tilde{u}(t_k))$ consecutively. The coefficients $c_{k,i}$ would depend on the interpolation that you use.

Here are a few options:
Operator Splitting
These will integrate $A$ and $B$ separately in a sequence. For example, the Lie-Trotter splitting is
$$
\begin{split}
v(0)&=u_n \\
v'&=A(v) \\
w(0)&=v(h) \\
w'&=B(w) \\
u_{n+1}&=w(h)
\end{split}
$$
The first ODE can be solved exactly while the second can be approximated with a Runge-Kutta method. There are many higher order operator splitting methods if needed, but they may require backward integration.
Multirate Infinitesimal
If you can solve
$$
u'(t)=A u(t) + f(t)
$$
exactly (a time dependent forcing included), this opens the door to the class of multirate infinitesimal step and multirate infinitesimal GARK methods. They combine a Runge-Kutta discretion for one partition with exact evolution of the other partition. An explicit Euler-based method for example:
$$
\begin{split}
v(0)&=u_n \\
v'(t)&=A(v(t))+B(u_n) \\
u_{n+1}&=v(h)
\end{split}
$$
Defect Correction
Let's define
$$
\begin{split}
u'&= A(u)+B(u)\\
v'&= A(v) \\
e(t)&=u(t)-v(t)
\end{split}
$$
You know the trajectory $v(t)$ exactly and have an "error" $e$ that satisfies
$$
\begin{split}
e'(t)&=u'(t)-v'(t)\\
&=A(u(t))+B(u(t))-A(v(t))\\
&=A(v(t)+e(t))+B(v(t)+e(t))-A(v(t))
\end{split}
$$
Now we can treat this with one step of a Runge-Kutta method to correct $v$. The hope is $e$ can be integrated more accurately than $u$. For example, a forward Euler discretization gives the method
$$
\begin{split}
v(0)&=u_n\\
v'&= A(v)\\
e_{n+1}&=h \cdot B(u_n)\\
u_{n+1}&=v(h)+e_{n+1}
\end{split}
$$
